# Substituting \ for \\ in column

Tags: sed, awk, mysql, escape-characters

I exported a column of thousands of salts from `mysql` for hashcat. Every instance of the character `\` was replaced with a double character `\\` in the exported column.

Is there a way to either `sed` or `awk` out the double `\\` and replace them with a single `\`?

Or is there a way to make mysql not export single `\` as a double character?

I use the following mysql command:

```
SELECT salt FROM user
INTO OUTFILE 'salts'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘:'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

The salts are three characters long and appear to use every character on the keyboard.

I have tried the following sed command:

```
sed 's/\(.^C\1/\1/g' file.txt
```

and it replaces double `\\` with single `\` but it also gets rid of a few other instances of double characters that I don't want it to.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to replace `\\` with `\` with `sed` you just need to escape each of `\`, so for example:

```
$ printf "%s\n" 'a\\b'
a\\b
$ printf "%s\n" 'a\\b' | sed 's/\\\\/\\/g'
a\b
```

But, frankly speaking it seems that in your case it would be better to correct mysql command, so I think this question is better suited to [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysql).